# rails select_tag association edit action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select

I have a Projects model that has_many tasks.

In the /tasks/new view i have a select tag which allows me to select the project for the new task:

```
<%= f.label :project_id %>
<%= f.select(:project_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@projects, "id", "name")) %><br />
```

This is in a _form.html.erb partial which is also called by the edit (tasks/8/edit).

However, in edit I get "You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!" Error.

I believe this is caused because the f.select is not calling the previously selected project from the Projects model.

Is there a way to make the call from the _form.html.erb?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If this does not help, post the partial call from the new.html.erb and the backtrace, but I believe it is one of two things:

You are not adding the `f` variable to the partial call. `f` is a local variable to the page, so you need to pass it to the partial by using the `:locals` option. Like this:

```
<%= render :partial, :locals => {:f => f} %>
```

Or there is the possibility that `@projects` is nil, be sure that it is being set in the controller.

Comment: Hmmm.  In the Tasks Controller I have:
def edit
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @project = @task.project
  end    

and after adding the :locals => {:f => f} to the edit.html.erb, I get undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x103af4f98>:0x103af3238>

Comment: I don't believe this is a partial issue.  I removed the partial and put it back in the edit.html.erb file.  I still get the "You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!" error.  I believe I am simply not passing the Project Id back into the edit template so it is confused by the f.select

Answer (score 0):

Try this!
`<%= render 'partial', :f => f %>`
i.e.
inside your edit action view you will have -
`<%= render 'from', :f => f %>`